# Where are good photography spots in Malaysia?

Tags: travel, locations

I am from Sweden and I've been in Kuala Lumpur for some time now and I wonder where I can find some good spots for shooting pictures. I've already been to Zoo Negara, but are there any other kind of places to visit?

I will stay in Kuala Lumpur until December, feel free to make suggestions. I'm much into photographing people and life.

Comment: This question may be more on topic and get better answers on [travel.se].

Comment: Amazing place... Went there for our honeymoon. You could try, Batu Caves, Anywhere round the city centre at night, if you can fly dont forget Bourneo - one word WOW. Also try Langkawi. All the best, A very jealous Rob

Comment: I kinda like the world-travel questions as long as they're photography-focused. They tend to get longish answers with pretty good suggestions from locals or other travel photographers, not just the random list of tips that would be less beneficial.

Answer (score 7):

What subject areas do you want to photograph?

KL has lots to see but is also an excellent gateway for short quick cheap (or cheapish) trips to elsewhere.

[**Cameron highlands**](https://www.google.co.nz/search?q=malaysia+aerial+walkway&hl=en&safe=off&prmd=imvns&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ei=7BuSUP3HBun_iAeKjoFI&ved=0CEkQsAQ&biw=1536&bih=830#hl=en&safe=off&tbm=isch&sa=1&q=cameron+highlands&oq=cameron+highlands&gs_l=img.3..0l10.5319.5319.2.5575.1.1.0.0.0.0.223.223.2-1.1.0...0.0...1c.1.Av343hySqCQ&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.&fp=b0e34b00d2ca7026&bpcl=37189454&biw=1536&bih=830) (daytrip) worthwhile.

[Malacca !!!](https://www.google.co.nz/search?q=malaysia+aerial+walkway&hl=en&safe=off&prmd=imvns&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ei=7BuSUP3HBun_iAeKjoFI&ved=0CEkQsAQ&biw=1536&bih=830#hl=en&safe=off&tbm=isch&sa=1&q=malacca+photography&oq=malacca+photography&gs_l=img.3..0i24j0i5i24.4575.9076.6.10345.12.12.0.0.0.0.270.2693.2-12.12.0...0.0...1c.1.DFhp7U_64Ak&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.&fp=b0e34b00d2ca7026&bpcl=37189454&biw=1536&bih=830) - VERY good. LONG day trip possible but go for a weekend. Bus trip cheapish and not very long. Hostels cheap. Old history, people, architecture. (Tourists!).

[FRIM](https://www.google.co.nz/search?q=malaysia+aerial+walkway&hl=en&safe=off&prmd=imvns&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ei=7BuSUP3HBun_iAeKjoFI&ved=0CEkQsAQ&biw=1536&bih=830#hl=en&safe=off&tbm=isch&sa=1&q=forest+research++frim++photography&oq=forest+research++frim++photography&gs_l=img.3...10478.16897.10.20837.18.18.0.0.0.7.234.3829.2-18.18.0...0.0...1c.1.uc619x-NUNU&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.&fp=b0e34b00d2ca7026&bpcl=37189454&biw=1536&bih=830)   (North KL). Good. Canopy walkway if open - ring and check explictly - internet news may be out of date.

If you have a little free $ and a few days (more is better) I'd **greatly** recommend a quick trip to Yogyakarta in Indonesia. A few hours flight. Air Asia does some ultra-low-cost flights if you book ahead and accept strange travel hours. Substantially cheaper than Malaysia. (I can recommend a superb and well priced guide if interested.)
 Stay in one of many many grotty dirt-cheap fun hostels off Malioboro St.
  Visit [**Borubadur !!!!**](https://www.google.co.nz/search?q=malaysia+aerial+walkway&hl=en&safe=off&prmd=imvns&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ei=7BuSUP3HBun_iAeKjoFI&ved=0CEkQsAQ&biw=1536&bih=830#hl=en&safe=off&tbm=isch&sa=1&q=borubadur+photography&oq=borubadur+photography&gs_l=img.3...87504.91358.12.92053.10.10.0.0.0.1.220.2117.2-10.10.0...0.0...1c.1.20ph5v73fqo&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.&fp=b0e34b00d2ca7026&bpcl=37189454&biw=1536&bih=830) - about as must-see as a photo site can get.
[**Prambanan**](https://www.google.co.nz/search?q=malaysia+aerial+walkway&hl=en&safe=off&prmd=imvns&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ei=7BuSUP3HBun_iAeKjoFI&ved=0CEkQsAQ&biw=1536&bih=830#hl=en&safe=off&tbm=isch&sa=1&q=prambanan++photography&oq=prambanan++photography&gs_l=img.3...58345.60898.14.61237.10.10.0.0.0.4.272.2210.2-10.10.0...0.0...1c.1.V8L5uVDtu8Y&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.&fp=b0e34b00d2ca7026&bpcl=37189454&biw=1536&bih=830)    - would be stunning if Borubadur was not there. 
[**Dieng PLateau**](https://www.google.co.nz/search?q=malaysia+aerial+walkway&hl=en&safe=off&prmd=imvns&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ei=7BuSUP3HBun_iAeKjoFI&ved=0CEkQsAQ&biw=1536&bih=830#hl=en&safe=off&tbm=isch&sa=1&q=dieng+plateau++photography&oq=dieng+plateau++photography&gs_l=img.3...70001.75718.16.76075.15.14.1.0.0.4.229.3021.2-14.14.0...0.0...1c.1.O_Xt3Fq_6nM&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.&fp=b0e34b00d2ca7026&bpcl=37189454&biw=1536&bih=830) - VERY LONG day trip - the journey itself is a stunning photo opportunity - one of the most amazing day drives of my life. Area is v good as well.

[Mt Merapi - volcano with attitude](https://www.google.co.nz/search?q=malaysia+aerial+walkway&hl=en&safe=off&prmd=imvns&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ei=7BuSUP3HBun_iAeKjoFI&ved=0CEkQsAQ&biw=1536&bih=830#hl=en&safe=off&tbm=isch&sa=1&q=merapi+++photography&oq=merapi+++photography&gs_l=img.3...247926.249438.18.250109.7.7.0.0.0.2.230.1490.2-7.7.0...0.0...1c.1.eMtd9STMw-w&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.&fp=b0e34b00d2ca7026&bpcl=37189454&biw=1536&bih=830) - and worthwhile even when quiet. Pillion motorcyle ride part way up the mountain. Sobering. Plus Merbabu near behind.

And much more ...

Note that airfares to a range of other Asian countries may cost well under $US100 - sometimes as low as about $US30 to eg Vietnam. Almost worth a weekend in a number of  other countries depending on finances.

---

If question moved to 'Travel" this answer could be taken with it.

Comment: Beautiful examples.... Makes me want to go back :)

Answer (score 1):

Awespot has a list of travel spots in Malaysia, with photos from Flickr (so it can help visualize what kind of photos you can make): [Malaysia](http://awespot.org/country/150/malaysia).

Interesting spots in the list:

- [Gunung Mulu National Park](http://awespot.org/spot/see/id/99039/n/gunung-mulu-national-park)
- [The snake temple](http://awespot.org/spot/see/id/313782/n/snake-temple)

Comment: Borneo has been on my to-go list for over 10 years! The Snake temple is in Penang which is very photogenic in itself, Georgetown particularly for ambiance.